# start an application with linux network namespaces using a bash function

Tags: bash

I have this script for exec an application and control any error on startup but need to perform a better control on this and use "network namespaces" to redirect this app on the netns with id "controlnet". With the last line the scripts goes ok, but Im redirecting to a blank screen, after exit from this I can see the application running but isn't initialized on "controlnet" namespaces.

If manually make the steps all is ok:

1. `sudo ip netns exec controlnet sudo -u $USER -i`
2. `cd /home/app-folder/`
3. `./hlds_run -game cstrike -pidfile ogp_game_startup.pid +map de_dust +ip 1.2.3.4 +port 27015 +maxplayers 12`

How to add this lines to the full bash?

Script used:

```
#!/bin/bash
function startServer(){
NUMSECONDS=`expr $(date +%s)`
until ./hlds_run -game cstrike -pidfile ogp_game_startup.pid +map de_dust +ip 1.2.3.4 +port 27015 +maxplayers 14 ; do
let DIFF=(`date +%s` - "$NUMSECONDS")
if [ "$DIFF" -gt 15 ]; then
NUMSECONDS=`expr $(date +%s)`
echo "Server './hlds_run -game cstrike -pidfile ogp_game_startup.pid +map de_dust +ip 1.2.3.4 +port 27015 +maxplayers 12 ' crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning..." >&2
fi
sleep 3
done
let DIFF=(`date +%s` - "$NUMSECONDS")
if [ ! -e "SERVER_STOPPED" ] && [ "$DIFF" -gt 15 ]; then
startServer
fi
}
sudo ip netns exec controlnet sudo -u myuser -i && cd /home/ && startServer
```

Comment: I'm inclined to argue that you're better off throwing out the existing script and starting fresh. There's very little there that's valuable -- `let`, `expr`, the `function` keyword, and other existing code runs afoul of best practices; see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key issue here is that `sudo -u myuser -i` starts a new shell session. Further commands, like `cd /home`, aren't run until **in** the shell session; instead, they're run **after** the shell session.

Thus, you need to move startServer **into** the `sudo` command, instead of running it **after** the `sudo` command.

One way to do this is by passing the code that should be run under `sudo` via a heredoc:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo ip netns exec controlnet sudo -u myuser bash -s <<'EOF'
startServer() {
  local endTime startTime retval
  while :; do
    startTime=$SECONDS
    ./hlds_run -game cstrike -pidfile ogp_game_startup.pid +map de_dust +ip 1.2.3.4 +port 27015 +maxplayers 14; retval=$?
    endTime=$SECONDS
    if (( (endTime - startTime) > 15 )); then
      echo "Server crashed with exit code $retval.  Respawning..." >&2
    else
      echo "Server exited with status $retval after less than 15 seconds" >&2
      echo "  not attempting to respawn" >&2
      return "$retval"
    fi
  sleep 3
  done
}

cd /home/ || exit
startServer
EOF
```

What's important here is that we're no longer running `sudo -i` and expecting the rest of the script to be fed into the escalated shell implicitly; instead, we're running `bash -s` (which reads script text to run from stdin), and passing both the text of the `startServer` function and a command that invokes it within that stdin stream.

Comment: Thank you! I make a test with your script but the system show me this
`usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] file ...`

Comment: Change it from `sudo myuser -c` to `sudo myuser bash -c`

Comment: On further consideration I decided to switch to an altogether different (heredoc-based) implementation, but if you read edit history you'll see a corrected version of the prior approach as well.

Comment: Perfect! So I have a little problem to bypass the user password with the script, it's possible to do that? I see examples like change user profile to "nologin" but in that way a potencial security door will be open.

Comment: `/etc/sudoers` can be configured with a very fine-grained whitelist. That said, I would generally consider running this kind of script from your process supervision system in the first place -- that way you aren't starting at a low-privilege user, escalating up, and then dropping back down; but are starting at the top and going down, so you don't need to configure any kind of escalation.

Comment: ...if you were going to stick with the original approach, in terms of what a `sudoers` rule might look like: `myuser: ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/ip netns exec controlnet /usr/bin/sudo -u myuser bash -s` -- that way, the only command you give `myuser` the right to run with no password is a command that moves back into their original account and starts bash there.

Comment: Excellent, really apreciated your help, that aproach with sudoers and "nopasswd" it's good tip I've never to do that. All works perfect! Tnks!

Comment: No lucky, I make the changes suggested on sudoers but only works for `/usr/sbin/ip` and for the second one prompts me for user password.

Comment: "only works for `/usr/sbin/ip`" -- isn't that what you want? You can substitute any code you want in the heredoc, but that's content that's run after permission was dropped down to the original account.

Comment: Yes that part it's ok but still required the sudo password for this part of the code `sudo -u myuser bash -s <<'EOF'`

Comment: Dropping permissions back *from* root to a regular user without a password is usually allowed by most operating systems' `/etc/sudoers` out-of-the-box. Easy enough to add, though, if it isn't for yours; the line `root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` will do the trick.

Comment: Sure with `NOPASSWD: ALL` I can bypass the password but it's really insecure. Have any other options or I need to mod the code?

Comment: See the `root` at the front? You're allowing it only for users that are root to start with. Anyone who's root to start with can change to any other user even without `sudo` *or* having a password, just by creating a copy of a shell (or any other program), `chown`ing it to the account they want and flagging it setuid -- or with plenty of other tricks. Which is to say -- **for the specific case of invocations from `root`**, there's absolutely no security gain to leaving out NOPASSWD, because there's no protecting yourself from a malicious user with root in the first place.